# VBScript create XML

Tags: xml, vbscript, msxml

I am creating a VBScript to create an XML file.
Got kind of stuck to get the following structure:

```xml
<Root>
  <tag>
    <a></a>
    <b></b>
    <c></c>
  </tag>
  <tag>
    <a></a>
    <b></b>
    <c><!-- this -->
      <c1></c1>
      <c2></c2>
      <c3></c3>
    </c>
  </tag>
</Root>
```

The code im using now is:

```vb
Set xmlDoc = CreateObject("Msxml2.DOMDocument.6.0")  

Set objRoot = xmlDoc.createElement("Root")  
xmlDoc.appendChild objRoot  

Set objRecord = xmlDoc.createElement("tag") 
objRoot.appendChild objRecord

Set objName = xmlDoc.createElement("a")  
objName.Text = "a"
objRecord.appendChild objName  

Set objName = xmlDoc.createElement("b")  
objName.Text = "b"
objRecord.appendChild objName

Set objName = xmlDoc.createElement("c")  
objName.Text = "c"
objRecord.appendChild objName
```

For `<tag>` #2 I'm basicly doing the same, but I don't see how to get another tag open for c1, c2 and c3. I have tried playing with the `appendChild`, but it's not visible or its there as another "tag" level.

I have been searching for an explanation of the `appendChild`, `objName`, and `objRecord`, but im failing to find some decent information.

Comment: So... you already have working code that appends elements to other elements. And your question is *"How can I append `c1`, `c2` and `c3` to `c`?"* - that's confusing. What does not work? Show the code that fails and the error you get.

Comment: First time playing around with vbscript and I didn't know "objName, objRecord"... where just variable names. Figured it out now :)... Now I get the whole appending story. My excuses

Comment: Nothing to make any excuses for. I just did not understand the question. For next time: Please also include the code that you have trouble with, not only the code that works.